# how to check for duplicate values when creating a random string in Coldfusion?

Tags: loops, random, coldfusion, while-loop, duplicates

I'm running `Coldfusion8/MySQL 5.0.88` and have table with ids, which are random strings a-z 0-9

I want to avoid duplicate entries when creating new records in the table, but I'm not sure how to set it up correctly.

Here is what I have:

```
<cfset variables.listOfAppIds = "">

<!--- get all ids --->
<cfquery datasource="db" name="app_ids">
    SELECT app_id FROM apps
</cfquery>

<!--- create comma-separated list --->
<cfloop query="app_ids">
    <cfset variables.listOfAppIds = variables.listOfAppIds & "," & app_ids.app_id>
</cfloop>

<!--- create random string and test if it is in listOfAppIds --->
<cfloop condition="#ListFindNoCase(variables.listOfAppIds, variables.rndString, ',')#">
    <cfset variables.stringLength = 10>
    <cfset variables.stringList = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z">
    <cfset variables.rndString = "">
    <cfloop from="1" to="#variables.stringLength#" index="i">
        <cfset variables.rndNum = RandRange(1, listlen(variables.stringList))>
        <cfset variables.rndString = variables.rndString & listGetAt(variables.stringlist, variables.rndNum)>
    </cfloop>
    <cfset variables.current_appId = variables.rndString>
</cfloop>
```

**Question:**
I'm not sure I'm using the `while-loop` correctly. Will this make sure no duplicates are found?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would re-consider the approach. You could use a GUID and then not check at all (which a lot of apps do).

Or create the new random ID then query the DB to see if you have a collision. That way the database is handling the same logic for you. Your logic would then be:

```
collision=true;
while (collision=true) {
    newID=RandomIdFunction();
    SELECT app_id FROM apps where app_id = newID;
    if query had no rows, set collision=false;
}
```

That will become slower as the database fills up the the chance of collisions gets higher, that's why I'd probably use the GUID approach if you can.

Comment: problem is I'm using these as user ids, where a user can have his own page design when the id is included in the URL. So while GUID will be unique and I don't need to check, I will have trouble handlig the URL with the GUID in it. So I don't think this will work.

Comment: Nevertheless, I like your suggested answer, too! So thanks a lot!

Comment: random != unique.  

If the values are being used in URLs then they're basically public values, so is there any reason not to just use a simple incrementing counter?

Comment: In addition to Peter's comments, do not forget about race conditions with db queries. Unless you exclusively lock the section that verifies
*and* inserts new values, it is possible for multiple threads to obtain the same ID. More so on busier sites. A counter would be simpler, though there is no reason you cannot pass a GUID/UUID in URL as long as it is encoded properly.